# Determining the Galois Group of Splitting Field of Cubic polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I wish to determine the Galois groups of $L$ over $Q$ when L is the splitting field of firstly, $x^3 − 4x + 2$ over $Q$ and secondly, $x^3 − 3x + 1$ over $Q$.
For another example, I know $x^3 + x^2 − 1$.  is irreducible by the rational root theorem. And the discriminant of the polynomial is $−23$, we have the group $S_3$ but I can't determine the Galois group for the above cubic polynomials in the same way, can I

Comment: Can you work out the discriminants of your polynomials?

Comment: opps yeah 148 and 81 respectively~

Comment: $148$ is not a square, but $81$ is. So the first has group $S_3$, and the second $A_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: Let 
 $d$ is discriminants polynomials.

if $\sqrt d \in \Bbb Q $ , then $Gal(L, \Bbb Q)\cong A_3$,
while if $\sqrt d \notin \Bbb Q $ , then $Gal(L, \Bbb Q)\cong S_3$